# How to improve data processing over log file

Tags: java, logging

I have some data processing to run over log file for example lines with timestamp.
And it takes 1 second to run over 1MB data. What can we do to perform this processing on 1TB data file in 10 seconds ?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more, how you are processing the file, what kind of processing are you doing? Pretty straight would be divided 1 TB file into small files and do parallel processing

Comment: These data are just text so it doesn't matter. How can divide into smaller files and introduce parralel processing ?

Comment: Isn't it possible to process the files when these are produced? Explain a bit more so that I can get the context of the problem? You can divide a file into small multiple files and simultaneously process different files using threads or using scalable microservice

Answer (score 0):

You can parallelize using threads and process different parts of the log file simultaneously.

That's assuming the processing on the logs is parallelizable and doesn't require sequential reading of the logs. It's also assuming that you have a fast enough hard drive (some spinning disk HDDs don't read 100MB/s, which is what would be required for 1TB/10s).